# Problems with WordPress Query. How To Re-order?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there way that you can order your WordPress query in so post display by the id oder set in the query? I was not able to find any additional information on the WordPress codex page that will show me how this can be done even if you set orderby to ID. Ideas?

```
$gp_query_args = array(
                // 'post_type'             => 'event',
                // 'meta_key'              => 'gp_event_date',
                // 'meta_value'            => date('Y/m/d'),
                // 'meta_compare'          => '>=',
                // 'orderby'               => 'meta_value',
                // 'order'                 => 'ASC',
                // 'posts_per_page'        => 4
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post__in' => array(172, 173, 174, 21826),
                'post__not_in' => array(181),
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order'

            );
```

Comment: What type of order you need? The one you specified by ids? And whats your current order is?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `'post__in'` parameter in your `orderby` like so:

```
$gp_query_args = array(
            // 'post_type'             => 'event',
            // 'meta_key'              => 'gp_event_date',
            // 'meta_value'            => date('Y/m/d'),
            // 'meta_compare'          => '>=',
            // 'orderby'               => 'meta_value',
            // 'order'                 => 'ASC',
            // 'posts_per_page'        => 4
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post__in' => array(172, 173, 174, 21826),
            'post__not_in' => array(181),
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'orderby' => 'post__in'

        );
```

This will display them in the order you list them in your `post__in` parameter line of the query. Check the last parameter in this list: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: No problem. Be sure to select my answer as your answer then please!

Comment: I dont think you can use post__in and post__not_in at the same time though, it's going to ignore the post__not_in statement. I guess it's fine since those 2 arrays dont overlap originally, but its not going to work when they overlap.

Comment: Correct. Didn't even notice he did that. There is no need for a `post__not_in` if you are already telling it to only use posts from the `posts__in` array